# I can't create new styles with SASS for AdminLTE

Tags: css, sass, compiler-errors, adminlte

I'm trying to develop an administration interface with AdminLTE as template but I am unable to add custom styles with SASS. I can override the CSS manually but I would prefer to change the global bootstrap variables.
I am trying to change the base colours but I get this error

The code:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~admin-lte/build/scss/bootstrap-variables';

// Custom Theme Color START
$custom-color: #00FF00;
$theme-colors: map-merge((
    'custom-color': $custom-color,
), $theme-colors);
```

The error:

```
Compilation Error
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The @import are copypasted from the AdminLTE docs for custom styles and I haven't touched anything yet

Structure:

```
(build)
    |_ (config)
    |_ (js)
    |_ (npm)
    |_ (scss)
         |_ (mixins)
         |_ (pages)
         |_ (parts)
         |_ (plugins)
         |_ //.scss files//
         |_ _bootstrap-variables.scss
         |_ //.scss files//
(dist)
   |_ (css)
        |_ (alt)
        |_ adminlte.css
        |_ adminlte.css.map
        |_ adminlte.min.css
        |_ adminlte.min.css.map
   |_ (img)
   |_ (js)
```

I can't seem to find myself the "bootstrap/scss/functions" files. I've already gone through all the folders but nothing. When downloading AdminLTE it says that it comes with all the neccesary files.

Comment: Please share the directory structure so the community can help what is wrong with the path

Answer (score 0):

i downloaded [bootstrap5.3.0](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v5.3.0-alpha1.zip) manually, and put it in the root folder of admin-lte:

```
admin-lte
    |_ (bootstrap)
         |_ (build)
         |_ (dist)
         |_ (js)
         |_ (nuget)
         |_ (scss)
         ...
    |_ (build)
    |_ (dist)
    |_ (docs)
    ...
```

but get another error

```
Error: $color: theme-color("primary") is not a color.
    ╷
166 │ $link-hover-color:          darken($link-color, 15%) !default;
    │                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  build\scss\_bootstrap-variables.scss 166:29  @import
  build\scss\adminlte-next.scss 9:9            root stylesheet
```